# VB.Net events: test if sender is another sub or function

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, sender

Is there any way to test if an event linked to a control is triggered by the program, rather than by user action?

I have a scroll bar which fires events when the user moves it. I want to be able to move the scroll bar programmatically elsewhere in the code without sending these events. i.e. events should only fire when the user interacts with the control, not when I move the control via code.

I also have radio buttons and numeric up/down controls I'd like to b able to do this with.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code, and why would programmatic scrolling be handled differently when you set it than when the user does it?

Comment: Your question illustrates why it is a good idea not to invoke events from code.  The event and your code could call a common scroll handling procedure though.

Comment: The code is spaghetti so not much use but the situation is quite simple. The reason it's required is because the app uses a modular collection of forms where the user might do something on one form which needs to be reflected on another form (e.g. a numeric up/down might be moved to the result of a calculation which the user did on a separate form, but the user needs to have the ability to change the up/down manually without triggering the event). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe better ways to do this but a quick way would be to use a boolean variable that you set when you are programmatically scrolling and unset it when you're done.  Then in your event check that before executing the logic.

```
If IsProgramaticScrolling = False Then
    ' Do whatever it's supposed to do when your program isn't
    ' scrolling via code.
End If
```